# Does this program that floors float in C really have undefined behavior?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

So the program is basically this:

```
float k=0.01345;
k *= 100;
k = (int)k ;
k /= (float) 100
```

A little context: a colleague needed, for some reason that I really don't remember, to floor a float value to just 2 decimal places.  I suggested this approach (because he said that he couldn't use `printf`, again I can't remember quite well why). But then another colleague said that this approach is not trustful, and could show undefined behavior. Is this really true?

I know that converting `float` to `int` has undefined behavior if the float is greater than `INT_MAX`, but this wouldn't occur in this function because it worked with numbers between 10000 and 0.

Comment: `k = int(k);` is invalid in C.

Comment: If you want to cast it you'd have to do this: `k = (int) k;`

Comment: Using value of uninitialized non-static local variable, which is indeterminate, invokes *undefined behavior*.

Comment: In addition to the above comments this doesn't round the value, it floors it. Doing this on a value like `6.789` will give you `6.78` instead of `6.79`

Comment: And further, not every value that has two decimal places is capable of being represented exactly in binary floating point.

Comment: @MikeCAT please turn that comment into an explained "Yes." answer.

Comment: Ignoring the obvious problem, this isn't a sane method of rounding. The problem is that the `k /= (float) 100;` does its own rounding.

Comment: So, The int(k) was typo. Sorry. @MikeCAT

Comment: I suspect that your question is not about the undefined behaviour rooted in first line and occuring in second. In that case please [edit] to focus your question on what you are actually asking about.

Comment: About it not rounding, just flooring, yes that is the intention. I expressed myself badly.  Already fixed it.

Comment: @FredLarson That is the answer that I'm looking for. I think that's what my colleague was trying to say. So what could happen is that my float would turn in another value close to that I wanted? Like 135 could become 1.348  ( when I divided it by 100) or something like that right ?

Comment: What will the function output for 888.20996?

Comment: The code has implementation-defined behavior, but not undefined-behavior (as long as the integer part of `k` is within the range of `int`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing that `k` is an in-scope, modifiable `float` variable with a well-defined value in the range 0 - 10000, as specified, the behavior of this code ...

```
k *= 100;
k = (int)k ;
k /= (float) 100;
```

... is well-defined in C.  It produces an approximation to the result of truncating `k`'s decimal value to two fractional digits.

However, very few exact decimal numbers with two significant decimal figures are exactly representable in binary floating point, so in general, an approximation is the best result you can hope for.  Note in particular that it is not necessarily stable: depending on the rounding mode in effect, if you apply the procedure again to the result, you may in some cases get a slightly different output.

Comment: Note that the code as written may increase the value of `k`, e.g. if `k` is 888.20996, then `k*100` would be rounded to 88821 because the arithmetically correct value 88820.996 is closer to that than to next smaller `float` value 88820.9921875.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach has some issues:

- `k` is uninitialized, but I suppose you just wrote `float k;` to specify the type of `k`.
- `k = int(k);` is not valid C code. You could write `k = (int)k;` but it would be more reliable to use the `floorf()` function (or `floor()` if your system does not have the `float` specific version): `k = floorf(k);`
- you do not *round* the value, but truncate it toward `0`. This is problematic because a value such as `1.999` will convert to `1.99` instead of `2.00`. You should use `roundf()` instead.

Here is a modified version:

```
float round2(float k) {
    return roundf(k * 100.0F) / 100.0F;
}
```

Note however that `float` cannot accurately represent most multiples of `0.01`. If you deal with currency amounts and want to avoid off by one errors due to precision errors, use a decimal type such as `_Decimal32` or `_Decimal64` or use integer types to handle whole amounts of cents.

Comment: Yeah, most of that was typos, and  I expressed myself badly with the 'round', already fixed it. Very sorry about that. 
I don't know if I could use float, because he still needed two decimal places. 
So the last thing, the multiples of   0.01, I think this is where my function has UB right?
So if I used _Decimal32 instead of float I could fix that?

Comment: The function has UB if the value is too large. The behavior is defined, but unexpected for many common values. Try `0.59` for example. `_Decimal32` is unlikely to be supported on many systems.

Comment: Aren't the multiplication and division the wrong way round in your `round2` function? (I think it should be `return roundf(k * 100.0F) / 100.0F;`.)

Comment: @IanAbbott: oops! absolutely!

Comment: A useful alternative to `return roundf(k * 100.0F) / 100.0F;` is `return (float)round(k * 100.0) / 100.0f;` as the `k * 100.0` will always be exact we then always get the correct rounding.

Answer (score 1):

> Does this program that floors float in C really have undefined behavior?

Yes, but you already know that:

> I know that converting float to int has undefined behavior if the float is greater than INT_MAX, but this wouldn't occur

With this constrain: no, the presented program has defined behavior.

--- Note that when `int` has 16 bits with `INT_MAX = 32767`, then `10000*100` will be way greater then `INT_MAX`. To be sure, make sure that the input is lower then `INT_MAX/100`.